# Cannot access class files from another package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, package

I have found similar problems, and i applied all the suggested solutions, but none works so far. I may have overlooked something.I am working on Maven multi-module project. In one of the packages, one of the java files is trying to access class file in another package. Class file is an external dependency provided in a jar file, installed on local repository. Jar file is added in Java Build path-> Libraries under Maven Dependencies. It is even included in classpath variable. But when I try to declare package and access it, I get error

```
The declared package "net.java.swingfx.waitwithstyle" does not match the expected 
 package "com.giag.fo.application.utility"
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions. I have tried anything I could find. I am clueless now.

Here is the [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/majndi314ccqkbn/Untitled.jpg) to get better idea

Comment: it looks to me like you have two classes with the same name, but in different packages, and you're trying to use them both somewhere.

Comment: It looks like you're mistaking the package keyword and the import keyword. The package keyword defines the package that your class is in. (Your first use of the package key word is perfectly correct) To use a class from a dependency, use the import key word to import the class and be able to instantiate new instances, or use static methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use import instead of the keyword package.
 like :-

```
package com.giag.fo.application.utility;
import net.java.swingfx.waitwithstyle.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
package net.java.swingfx.waitwithstyle;
```

use

```
import net.java.swingfx.waitwithstyle.InfiniteProgressAdapter;
```

You can read more about [package and import here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html)